# how to change the loading status of a page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have pages that start the state of the variable 'loading' as true, I want that after loading the components this state changes to false and the page appears. How could you do that?

I'm doing it this way but it's not working, go straight to the page without rendering all the components:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { 
    loading: true
   }
}

componentDidMount() {  
 this.setState({ loading: false });   
}

render() {
  return (
    this.state.loading ? <Preloader /> : <div><div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you try [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) ?

Comment: That won't work since he is using class components; I know the solution and will post soon.

Comment: Well, [ComponentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) is the solution.

Comment: how could you use with ComponentDidUpdate?

Answer (score 0):

In your parent component you need a loadingStatus in state, and a method to toggle that status. You then conditional render the preloader with the loadStatus, but not the component you are waiting to load. Instead, pass that component both loadingStatus and the toggle method,

```
import React from 'react'
import SlowComponent from './SlowComponent'
import Preloader from './Preloader'

class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    loadingStatus: true,
    apiData: {propA:'', propB:''}
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
      let apiCall = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(()=> resolve({propA: 'A', propB: 'B'}), 2000);
      })
      let results = await apiCall; 
      this.setState({apiData:results},this.toggleStatus)
  }

  toggleStatus = () => {
    this.setState({loadingStatus: false})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
          {this.state.loadingStatus && <Preloader/>}
          {!this.state.loadingStatus && <SlowComponent apiData={this.state.apiData} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
 
  }

 export default App;
```

Inside the slow component's componentDidMount you then call the toggle method. Using the loadingStatus, you can also conditionally render the style of the most outer tag to display none incase of partially rendering. Note, I used set timeout to mimic the delayed rendering.

```
import React from 'react';

class SlowComponent extends React.Component {

    
    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout( ()=> this.props.toggleStatus(), 2000);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div style={this.props.loadingStatus ? {display: "none"} : {}}>
                Slow Component
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default SlowComponent;
```

And here is the preloader incase you wanted to piece it together

```
import React from 'react';

class SlowComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                Slow Component <br/>
                {this.props.apiData.propA} <br/>
                {this.props.apiData.propB}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default SlowComponent;

export default Preloader;
```

Comment: hey thanks. that way I guarantee that the upload will work until all requests to the backend are loaded?

Comment: So the component is relient on API data to render? If that's the case it'd be a little different; you need to make the API call 1 level up in either the parent or a wrapper component, and then trigger the loading status on completion.

Comment: I redid my answer to better illustrate your issue